# Como buscar dados de um Oracle sys_refcursor via PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

Tenho um Pacote com uma função onde o retorno da mesma é um `sys_refcursor`:

```
FUNCTION getConfigPlaca(placa_aux VARCHAR2) RETURN sys_refcursor;
```

Se consulto essa função com um "from dual" recebo:

```
{<SENSOR=1,LIMITE_MAXIMO=+28,LIMITE_MINIMO=+24,LIMITE_ATIVO=0>,<SENSOR=2,LIMITE_MAXIMO=+40,LIMITE_MINIMO=+01,LIMITE_ATIVO=0>,}
```

Não estou conseguindo tratar esses dados corretamente buscando através do PHP, alguém poderia me dar uma pista de como posso proceder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No php existe uma biblioteca OCI8, que é utilizada para por exemplo para este tipo de problema.

No php.net tem um exemplo de como utilizar este tipo de retorno que é um tipo de dado existente apenas no ORACLE.
No teu caso você usaria o **oci_new_cursor** que aloca e retorna um cursor.

Link da explicação: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-new-cursor.php]

Comment: Solucionou meu problema, obrigado;

Comment: Show, se puder aumentar o nível da minha resposta para um nível acima ficaria agradecido :)